# How to keep rows with more than three columns greater than (in Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

i'd like to know how to keep rows in a Pandas dataframe in which more than 3 of its columns have values greater than 0.8
Here is an example:

```
companyInfo = pd.DataFrame()
companyInfo['col1'] = [0,0,0,0,0]
companyInfo['col2'] = [0,0.9,0,0,0]
companyInfo['col3'] = [0,0,0.85,0,0]
companyInfo['col4'] = [0,0,0,0,0]
companyInfo['col5'] = [0,0.2,0,0,0.09]
companyInfo['col6'] = [0,0,0.3,0,0.87]
companyInfo['col7'] = [0,0,0.2,0.4,0.82]
```

In this case, only the last row would be kept as it has at least 3 columns greater than 0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the masking for values greater than 0.8 and then call `sum()` on `axis=1` and then check if the sum is greater than 3

```py
companyInfo[(companyInfo>0.8).sum(axis=1)>3]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Columns: [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7]
Index: []
```

*Empty because you don't have any value matching this criteria*

But for some other criteria:

```py
companyInfo[(companyInfo>=0.2).sum(axis=1)>=3]

#output
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
2     0   0.0  0.85     0   0.0   0.3   0.2
```